# Open another Mac app

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

In my app I would like to open another app that is installed on the User's Mac (such as iPhoto). I am not sure what I should be looking for in the documentation. What is this called and how should I do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 30):

**XCode 11 • MacOS Catalina 10.15 • Swift 5**

*NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication* is deprecated and starting from the MacOS 10.15 the new function *NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication* shall be used.

---

Example - open terminal application by its bundle id

```
guard let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Terminal") else { return }

let path = "/bin"
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.arguments = [path]
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                                   configuration: configuration,
                                   completionHandler: nil)
```

---

Example - open terminal application by its path

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app", isDirectory: true) as URL

let path = "/bin"
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.arguments = [path]
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                                   configuration: configuration,
                                   completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: What to use instead of NSWorkSpace on M1 Mac? (UIKit only, no AppKit)

Comment: This doesn't work and doesn't give any error message as to why that might be. I'm not even trying to change the app I want to launch yet, it doesn't even launch Terminal when copied verbatim. Also the first method cannot be used outside of a function because of the return, so it's not clear how it's supposed to be implemented.

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 5 or later**

```
import Cocoa

func openPhotos() -> Bool {
    if let photosApp = FileManager.default.urls(
        for: .applicationDirectory,
        in: .systemDomainMask
    ).first?.appendingPathComponent("Photos.app") {
        return NSWorkspace.shared.open(photosApp)
    }
    return false
}
```

---

Usage:

```
if openPhotos() {
    print(true)
}
```

---

Or using launchApplication with the app name parameter in the method:

```
import Cocoa

func openApp(_ named: String) -> Bool {
    NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(named)
}
```

---

Usage:

```
if openApp("Photos") {
    print(true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSWorkspace class written by Swift/Cocoa.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchApplication:

Answer (score 3):

`let task = NSTask.launchedTaskWithLaunchPath(<#path: String#>, arguments: <#[AnyObject]#>)` will probably do what you want

Comment: Thank you Thomas! As an example, if you wanted to launch a unique instance of Unity, you could use: let _ = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity", arguments: ["-na"])

Comment: @TigerCoding Thanks for the example. Your example was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 3):

I second the answer by *vookimedlo* - unfortunately, I cannot yet comment (silly reputation limit) so I post this as an extra answer.

This is just one caveat, which might not affect too many: while `launchApplication()` accepted a path to an executable (e.g. "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp"), this will result in an error (lacking privileges) with `openApplication(::)`. You have to supply the path to the app bundle ("MyApp.app") instead.

Of particular interest when you try to make a helper ("launcher") to add as a login item. See the following and keep my comment in mind:

https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/
(GREAT article by Tibor Bödecs)

BTW, as for *vookimedlo*'s code: in my experience, you don't need to specify the `OpenContext.arguments` with `[path]`, you can simply pass a default `NSWorkspace.OpenContext()`...

Comment: This saved me hours of troubleshooting. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that.  The most efficient is to use fvork and execve - see `man vfork` and `man execve`.

Less efficient but more flexible is to use the `system` library call.  What that actually does is runs a shell - like bash - then passes the string you provide, to bash. So you can set up pipelines, redirection and such.

Or you can send an Apple Event to the Finder: "Tell Finder Open iPhoto".

In the first two cases you want to launch the executable inside the bundle, that is, `/Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhoto`.

Try the above from the command line, in the Terminal:

```
$ /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhoto
```

You'll see the iPhoto App launch.