# how to open local app through safari web extension?

Tags: swift, macos, safari-extension

Given the allowed bidirectional communication between the JS component and the local (Mac) app, how can I open the local application using a message from the web component?

I am able to send messages between the components but the current safari web extensions context does not allow the usage of `UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL` (as in, UIApplication is not really loaded).

Comment: `UIApplication` on macOS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open another Mac app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505022/open-another-mac-app)

Comment: UIApplication is not loaded into the context of Safari Extensions. At least not in the local-extension flow. Below you will find my solution.

Comment: Is the question about macOS, iOS or Mac Catalyst?

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIApplication` cannot be used in this context, `NSWorkspace.shared.open(<App url>)` did the trick.

Comment: this can open the Mac App associated with the Safari Web Extension? Assuming the Mac app is exited already.  Thanks.

Comment: In my experience, yes, it did.