# Open another Mac app from Mac Catalyst application

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

In my app I would like to open another my app that is installed on the User's Mac.

I have already seen [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505022/open-another-mac-app)

which suggest

```
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                               configuration: configuration,
                               completionHandler: nil)
```

But according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172700-openapplication) it is not available for MacCatalyst

Please suggest

Comment: Hey! Did you ever figure this out? Just going through the same thing. I would like to open Photoshop