# Is 'Launch Services' used to open other apps from current app in MacOS

Tags: macos, launch-services

I have a use case where I want to launch an app from my current app. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505022/open-another-mac-app), which used NSWorkspace shared object and its API's to launch the other app. I m able to launch the other app using this shared object.

But then I came across this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/launch_services) . These are the Launch Services in MacOS. It also states that using launch services we can launch other apps. I have not tried this approach as I did not find any proper resources on how to use these launch services.

I wanted to know which is the right way and is it even possible using these launch services approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch Services is about the pairing between document types and apps that can open them. For example, if you see a text file in the Finder and you double click it and TextEdit launches, that is Launch Services at work.

Since what you are doing is unrelated to that, don't use Launch Services.